# Two ArrarList in one RecyclerView in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Hi i use recyclerview with two arraylist in kotlin but i have problem with how to use positions When we have two arraylist in one recyclerview
in fact i need two arraylist in my recyclerview , one for headers item and one for child item
thank you
My Sample Code(With error about positions):
Please Help!

**My Adapter Code**

```
package com.example.recyclerviewpro

import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView


class AdapterRecyclerView(private val listViewType: List<Int>, val HeaderList : List<HeaderModel>, val ContentList : List<ContentModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        val Header_ITEM = 1
        val Child_ITEM = 2
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            Header_ITEM -> ViewHolderItemA(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_header, parent, false))
            else -> ViewHolderItemB(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val viewType = listViewType[position]
        when (viewType) {
            Header_ITEM -> {
                val viewHolderA = holder as ViewHolderItemA
                viewHolderA.bind(ContentList.get(position))
            }
            else -> {
                val viewHolderA = holder as ViewHolderItemB
                viewHolderA.bind(HeaderList.get(position - ContentList.size), position)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listViewType.count()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = listViewType[position]

    open inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    inner class ViewHolderItemA(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textView1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view)
        fun bind(header : ContentModel){
            textView1.text = header.Title
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolderItemB(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView){
        val content : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewC)
        val content2 : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewC2)
        fun bind(cm : HeaderModel , position: Int){
            content.text = cm.title
            content2.text = cm.price
        if (position % 2 == 1){
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.White))
        }else{
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.Gray))
        }
        }

    }

}
```

**Error**

```
2019-10-01 10:08:19.090 3724-3724/com.example.recyclerviewpro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerviewpro, PID: 3724
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
        at com.example.recyclerviewpro.AdapterRecyclerView.onBindViewHolder(AdapterRecyclerView.kt:34)
        at com.example.recyclerviewpro.AdapterRecyclerView.onBindViewHolder(AdapterRecyclerView.kt:11)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-10-01 10:08:19.090 3724-3724/com.example.recyclerviewpro E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-10-01 10:08:19.134 3724-3724/com.example.recyclerviewpro I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3724 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I don't see how this can work. Where are you defining how many items are after each header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume listViewType is used as indicator of HeaderList and ContentList items. Which means for example:

If you have 3 HeaderList items and 3 ContentList items. Your listViewType list should look like this [1,1,1,2,2,2]. Where 1 represents Header type element, and 2 represents Content type element.

I think the problem is that you don't pass correct listViewType. It is necessary for that list to be sorted, and to be correct representation of combination of ContentList and HeaderList.

Comment: Can you please share code of your Actvity/Fragment where you instantiate AdapterRecyclerView?